# Check the permission of user when calling `ADODB.connection.open`

Tags: sql, vba, adodb, user-permissions

I was stucked for many week on the following :

I need to delete and insert to SQL database using VBA Excel.

The code used to connect to database is :

```
sConnString= "string for the connexion to the database"
conn.Open sConnString, "username", "password"
Debug.Print conn.State
```

Here the answer is `1`, which according to the Microsoft documentation, means that the connexion is opened.

Then I try to execute an SQL query, using the following code :

```
varSQL = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE specificColumn = '" & specificVariable & "'"
Set Command1 = New ADODB.Command
With Command1
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
End With
With Command1
    .CommandText = varSQL
    .Execute NbRecordsAffected
End With
```

This returns access denied for the `DELETE` query

I want to know if the user with `username` has the permission to do the query, so I can be sure that the error comes form another thing

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi - One approach would be to handle the error to know when the `Access Denied` pops up. The other, which would depend on your database, would be to query what the permissions are for the given user, and store/check that in your app

Comment: "SQL database" is not very specific - there may be more useful suggestions if you tell us what actual database you're using.  Eg: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6828/sql-server-login-user-permissions-fn-my-permissions/

Comment: @TimWilliams   Thanks for the remark, I am actually working with Microsoft SQL, so the link on your comment seems useful , I will try it to see if I can get some information

Answer (score 0):

Consider capturing the more informative error via the ADO error collections using VBA error handling where you may receive if using an SQL Server database:

> The DELETE permission was denied on the object 'mytable', database 'mydatabase' schema dbo

```vb
Sub Run_SQL()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
     Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, Command1 AS ADODB.Command

     '...your full code...

ExitHandle:
    ' RELEASE RESOURCES
    Set Command1 = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandle:
    ' RAISE EVERY CONNECTION ERROR
    Dim myError As ADODB.Error
    For Each myError In conn.Errors
        Msgbox myError.Number & " - " & myError.Description, "RUNTIME ERROR", vbCritical
    Next myerror
    Resume Exit_Handle

End Sub
```

Comment: It raises execution error 13 : Incompatible type

Comment: Are you sure that error is due to user permission or your non-parameterized/concatenated condition: `WHERE specificColumn = '" & specificVariable & "'"`? Try isolating specific issue for debugging.

Comment: `conn.Errors` type is different from VBA Error. perhaps it has a particular type. When I debug, the error was on the line `For Each myError In conn.Errors`

Comment: You are right. See edit using `ADODB.Error`.